# Underscore -> var _ function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Can anyone explain exactly what it is going on here?

It is the heartbeat of the underscore library as it exposes the `_` for use, but how is this exposing the `_` as something that is publicly available for use?

```
var _ = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
  };
```

If I type `_` into the console the following is returned:

```
_(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
  }
```

However..... directly above we have

```
var root = this;
```

If you type `root` into the console it returns `root is not defined` as it is protected within the scope of the IIFE. It seems to be a great example of the Principle of Least Privilege.

I am nearly certain that it is the use of `new _(obj)` that exposes the `_` but an explanation of this function would be appreciated. What would be an example of an `obj` been passed in? One of the underscore methods?

The source, and this section in particular can be [found here](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-10) if more context is required.

Comment: An example for `obj` would be anything that is wrapped - e.g. in `_([1,2,3]).map(…)` it's the array.

Comment: @Bergi ah ok, and is it the `new` keyword that makes it available in the global scope?

Comment: No, the `new` keyword has nothing to do with scope. It just constructs an instance, like any constructor does.

Comment: @Bergi got it, lot clearer now

Comment: To expand on what @Bergi said, keep in mind that `_(x).f()` and `_.f(x)` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below those lines, there is some code:

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    exports = module.exports = _;
  }
  exports._ = _;
} else {
  root._ = _;
}
```

If you are in a browser environment, `exports` will be `undefined`, so `root._` will be set to `_`. `root` is set to `this` at the top, and the default value of `this` is `window`.

Comment: I understand all that, but how come if I type `root` into the console nothing is returned?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on that line (you can usually do this by clicking the line number in the gutter) and typing `root` into the console.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald: You already explained it yourself in the question: "*… as it is protected within the scope of the IIFE.*"

Comment: @Bergi, but what I want to know is why `_` is not also protected by the `IIFE`? that is where my confusion lies, and also what are the `obj` been passed in as arguments

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald `_` is set as a property of `window`. Try running `window.x = 2` in your console, then checking the value of `x`. It should be `2`. The same thing is happening with `_`.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald: The local `_` is assigned to a global property, like `window._ = …`. There will be multiple variables with the name, in the console and your scripts you only can access the global one.

Comment: @JF ah ok, this makes sense! thanks for clearing that confusion up